# render without going to action

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm calling an action helper automatically in the bootstrap so I don't need to call it in the action itself, it gets called automatically.

In the action helper I want to do a render and then stop execution so that it doesn't go to the called action as it usually does. What should I use to stop execution and prevent it from going to the action?

- If I do exit, it doesn't take me to the action, but it doesn't do the render either.
- If I do return, it still goes to the action (leaves the action helper and continues and the next step is the action itself so it executes it)

-

```
$action = //
if (/*something*/){
    $action->render('second');
    return;   //it goes to the action after that
    exit;     //the render doesn't work
}
```

Comment: maybe: echo $action->render('second') ? Or do you want to go to an other action? Than inside your controller $this->_forward('second');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would return a boolean value from the action helper and then render from there. So in your action helper:

```
if(/* something */) {
  $this->_helper->viewRenderer('second.phtml');
  return false;
} else
  return true;
```

And in your action:

```
if($this->_helper->yourHelper()) {
 //Do whatever your action should do otherwise
} //No need for an else, the render will call second.phtml automatically
```